# Webpack with requirejs and backbone errors out in browser

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, webpack

Here is my webpack config:

```
{
    entry: './public/static/js/app/app.js',
    output: {
        path: './public/static/dist/js/',
        filename: 'app-compiled.js',
        pathinfo: true
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /public\/static.*\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw'
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.dependencies.LabeledModulesPlugin()
    ],
    resolveLoader: {
        alias: {
            'text': 'raw',
        },
        root: ['./public/static/js/app']
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js'],
        root: [
            path.resolve('./public/static/js/app'),
        ],
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        alias: {
            'backbone': path.resolve('./public/static/js/lib/backbone.js'),
            'backbone.relational': path.resolve('./public/static/js/lib/backbone-relational.js'),
            'backbone.wreqr': path.resolve('./public/static/js/lib/backbone.wreqr.min.js'),
            'marionette': path.resolve('./public/static/js/lib/marionette.js'),
            'text': path.resolve('./public/static/js/lib/text.js'),
            'smoke': path.resolve('./public/static/js/lib/smoke.js'),
            '_': path.resolve('./public/static/js/lib/underscore.js'),
            'underscore.inflection': path.resolve('./public/static/js/lib/underscore.inflection.js'),
            'chosen': path.resolve('./public/static/js/lib/chosen.js'),
            'spin': path.resolve('./public/static/js/lib/spin.min.js'),
            'uuid': path.resolve('./public/static/js/lib/uuid-v4.min.js'),
            'ladda': path.resolve('./public/static/js/lib/ladda.min.js'),
            'jquery': path.resolve('./public/static/js/lib/jquery.js')
        }
    },
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'sourcemap',
};
```

The problem I am seeing in the browser is `root is undefined`. The compiled code that reads that is `var previousBackbone = root.Backbone;`

Comment: A similar issue -- same line, different error ( "main.js:5484 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Backbone' of undefined" ). Found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need Babel to transpile node nodules such as Backbone. We want Webpack to use the pre-built javascript inside a given npm package. In not excluding the transpiling of node_modules, I expect Babel is making some optimisations to Backbone that it shouldn't. To exclude node_modules, add an exclude property to your babel loader e.g.

```
{
    test: /public\/static.*\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
}
```